# Android Studio gradle's "calculate task graph" takes too long

Tags: android-studio, gradle

When building app in Android Studio, it takes too long (besides I use offline mode, latest gradle, etc).

I investigate, and see progress of each task, where most time is spent in **Calculate task graph** item.

[image]

Every single gradle task that I choose from *Gradle* tool window spend at least 9 seconds in this *Calculate task graph*.

How can I speed up this task, and why it takes so long, when other gradle tasks are usually cached (UP-TO-DATE)? I could possibly build much faster, but each app build adds 10 seconds, which is killer of productivity.

Any advice is welcome. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Inside "Calculate task graph" phase Gradle also appears to be resolving dependencies (not sure why this isn't in its own separate time slot, it could be a bug). That means that you can follow [Gradle's guide to dependency resolution performance.](https://guides.gradle.org/performance/#dependency_resolution)

What helped in my project:

- Remove any unused repositories (removing `mavenLocal()` made the biggest difference)
- Remove any SNAPSHOT libraries and repositories that contain snapshots (use stable versions instead)
- Interestingly enough, disabling Android Plugin's jetifier (set `android.enableJetifier=false` in `gradle.properties`) seems to also help significantly but of course that means that you cannot depend on libraries that did not migrate to AndroidX yet. It appears this is a [bug in jetifier](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/141128458).

Answer (score 0):

this might help : [Speed Up Gradle Build In Android Studio](https://hackernoon.com/speed-up-gradle-build-in-android-studio-80a5f74ac9ed)

when i create a new project , i usually replace my `gradle.properties` like this :

```
org.gradle.parallel=true
org.gradle.daemon=true
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
```

it makes my gradle much faster.